# Displaying integer value in a text view in a Dialog Window in Android

Tags: java, android-layout

Can Anyone suggest why integer value is not getting displayed in a text view in a Dialog Window in Android. I am using the below code to display a Dialog Window

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnAccountInfo) {
        this.showDialog(DIALOG_ACCOUNT);
    } 

}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ACCOUNT:
        final Dialog info = new Dialog(this);
        info.setContentView(R.layout.accountinfo);
        info.setTitle("User Account for MobileProtect");
        backInfo = (Button) info.findViewById(R.id.backInfo);
        userNumber1 = (TextView)info.findViewById(R.id.textUserNumber1);
        userNumber2 = (TextView)info.findViewById(R.id.textUserNumber2);
        userEmail = (TextView)info.findViewById(R.id.textUserEmail);
         Log.d("User Number", "Dialog: "+number1+number2);
        userNumber1.setText(number1);
        userNumber1.setText(number2);
        userEmail.setText(email);
        backInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                info.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return info;

    }
    return null;
}
```

Number1 and Number1 are not getting displayed in the Dialog Window whereas Email is getting displayed in the Dialog Window. I have checked the logcat i am getting the values for number1 and number2 and that too in an integer format.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Passing an int to the `setText` method will call an overload that interprets the argument as an *resource id*. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) for more information. Use this instead

```
userNumber1.setText(Integer.toString(number1));
```

Also consider improving you variable names and formatting your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `number1` & `number2` are not `String` values.

Try the following:

```
    userNumber1.setText( Integer.toString( number1 ) );
    userNumber2.setText( Integer.toString( number2 ) );
```

(Assuming that `number1` & `number2` are int values)